# how to get changed text in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>hi</td>
    </tr>        
</table>
<button id="change" onclick="change()">change</button>
<script>
    function change(){
        $("table").empty();
        var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
        $tr.append( $("<td>bye</td>") );
    }
</script>
```

```java
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
WebElement change= driver.findElement(By.id("change"));
change.click();

WebElement td=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*table/tr/td[1]"));
System.out.println(td.getText());
```

I expected "bye", but it printed "hi".

How can I get dynamically changed text?

Comment: Did the text change on the website? Does a `sleep` after the `click()` help?

Comment: i omitted $("table").append($tr); here but dont care about this

Comment: yes the text changed on the website. sleep doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the use of `WebDriverWait` explicit waits you can get the initial element text content. Then to wait for that text to no more be presented in that element after the click and then to get the new element text content. As following:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20);
WebElement td =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*table/tr/td[1]"));
String oldText = td.getText();
driver.findElement(By.id("change")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//*table/tr/td[1]"), oldText)));
System.out.println(td.getText());
```

Comment: it said like Expected condition failed: waiting for condition to not be valid: text ('hi') to be present in element found by By.xpath: //*table/tr/td[1] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Are you sure it is the same element presenting the initial and the changed texts? Maybe element locator is changed by the click or something else?

Comment: in actual page, its //*[@id="searchTable"]/tbody/tr[1]],  //*[@id="searchTable"]/tbody/tr[1]. they are same

Comment: can you share a link to that page? I have such method in my project and it works.

Comment: in actual code, the click button calls this function. `function searchOrder(){ $.ajax({  ~~~ success:function(data){ searchOrderDisplay(data) }   }) }`.   and searchOrderDisplay makes table empty and remake table. maybe because i used 2 functions?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. Need to actually debug that to see what happens on your side. Again, the approach I shared here works in my real project. The code is partially copy-pasted.

Comment: What's wrong with your link? I tried it some time before and it worked, but I still not completed my  researches. Now it can't be opened.

Comment: sorry i found your way is working well. so i turned off to try in other project